# Sum based on rows.count

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add up the numbers that are in a column, but the column of numbers varies so I'm using the `Rows.Count` instead of a set number of rows such as `"a1:a5"`. Each time I run this I get the row count (represented as rngcount) but instead of the sum of the cells within the row count (rngcount) I get the row count again.

I was getting an object error `(1004)` until I added `"a"` to `.Range("a" & rngcount)` but I admit I'm not sure why the `"a"` is needed as I thought the `rngcount`would be all that is needed to `Sum`.

So Unfortunately two issues in one post.

```
Sub simpleSUM()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rngcount As Integer

Set rng1 = Range("b1") 'This indicates how many cells are in use
Set rng2 = Range("b2") 'This indicates the sum of the cells that are in use

rngcount = cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

rng1.Value = rngcount
rng2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("a" & rngcount))
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that row counting variables **must** be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim rngcount As Long`. I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code now only counts the last row. The variable `rngcount` returns the last rownumber in the range, instead of the whole range.

It should work if you use

```
rng2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A" & rngcount))
```

Comment: Yes. Might also be worth noting that best practice is to declare `rngcount As Long` instead of `As Integer`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll click the check as soon as the time limit allows. I do have a follow up question which is why is "a1;a" needed? My thinking up until this point is that the range is defined in the variable "rngcount" so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Without "a1:a" I know there is no object found, but I go back to my initial thinking that the object is defined earlier as the integer 'rngcount' ... I am trying to mark up my comment correctly but I cannot find  ` on my keyboard

Comment: The range is identified by a string, such as "A1:A5". The rngcount variable is only a number. So to complete the range, you combine the "A1:A" part with the number from rngcount to get a complete string that can be identified as a range.

Comment: Fair enough, if you have time for one more question, why the need for  "a1:a" instead of just "a". I could be wrong (probably I am) but by declaring "a" does that not capture the entire range of column a. That will be my last question on this, thank you for your time.

Comment: @officemanager2 if it helps, say the last row is 200. The revised line of code is equivalent to the formula `=SUM(A1:A200)`. Your original code would be equivalent to `=SUM(A200)`, which just takes the last cell into account.

Comment: No, because let's say rngcount = 5, then "a" & rngcount will result in "A5", which points to the cell A5. The entire column is identified by "A:A", but since you want to stop at the last row, say 5, you also need to specify the start of the range. "A:A5" for instance would cause an error.